# 404 Category not found in Joomla 1.7

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7

I dont know why suddenly this page cannot be viewed. Anyone face this problem before? The other pages are fine.
http://goo.gl/nQ49i

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found the solution by modifying this file : components/com_content/views/category/view.html.php

Comment out :

```
if ($parent == false) {
    return JError::raiseError(404, JText::_('JGLOBAL_CATEGORY_NOT_FOUND'));
}
```

Core hacks are not the best but I couldn't fix it without it.